# URLError python csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

I am totally new to programming python and while trying to do an exercise, I have a problem loading up a csv file.
The machine prints me a URLError and output exceeds the size limit (despite increasing the size limit).

I tried everything I read on the internet but nothing seems to fully work. I installed various libraries to open files and read datafrales and everything but nothing works.

I put the error code down below (the first lines are the beginning of the file and then you have the error message). Any help would be more than appreciated !! :

| 3 | ? | alfa-romero | gas | std | two | convertible | rwd | front | 88.60 | \ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | ? | alfa-romero | gas | std | two | convertible | rwd | front | 88.6 |
| 1 | 1 | ? | alfa-romero | gas | std | two | hatchback | rwd | front | 94.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 164 | audi | gas | std | four | sedan | fwd | front | 99.8 |
| 3 | 2 | 164 | audi | gas | std | four | sedan | 4wd | front | 99.4 |
| 4 | 2 | ? | audi | gas | std | two | sedan | fwd | front | 99.8 |
| .. | .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 199 -1 | 95 | volvo | gas | std | four | sedan | rwd | front | 109.1 |  |
| 200 -1 | 95 | volvo | gas | turbo | four | sedan | rwd | front | 109.1 |  |
| 201 -1 | 95 | volvo | gas | std | four | sedan | rwd | front | 109.1 |  |
| 202 -1 | 95 | volvo | diesel | turbo | four | sedan | rwd | front | 109.1 |  |
| 203 -1 | 95 | volvo | gas | turbo | four | sedan | rwd | front | 109.1 |  |

| ... | 130 | mpfi | 3.47 | 2.68 | 9.00 | 111 | 5000 | 21 | 27 | 13495 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ... | 130 | mpfi | 3.47 | 2.68 | 9.0 | 111 | 5000 | 21 | 27 | 16500 |
| 1 | ... | 152 | mpfi | 2.68 | 3.47 | 9.0 | 154 | 5000 | 19 | 26 | 16500 |
| 2 | ... | 109 | mpfi | 3.19 | 3.40 | 10.0 | 102 | 5500 | 24 | 30 | 13950 |
| 3 | ... | 136 | mpfi | 3.19 | 3.40 | 8.0 | 115 | 5500 | 18 | 22 | 17450 |
| 4 | ... | 136 | mpfi | 3.19 | 3.40 | 8.5 | 110 | 5500 | 19 | 25 | 15250 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | .. | .. | ... |
| 199 | ... | 141 | mpfi | 3.78 | 3.15 | 9.5 | 114 | 5400 | 23 | 28 | 16845 |
| 200 | ... | 141 | mpfi | 3.78 | 3.15 | 8.7 | 160 | 5300 | 19 | 25 | 19045 |
| 201 | ... | 173 | mpfi | 3.58 | 2.87 | 8.8 | 134 | 5500 | 18 | 23 | 21485 |
| 202 | ... | 145 | idi | 3.01 | 3.40 | 23.0 | 106 | 4800 | 26 | 27 | 22470 |
| 203 | ... | 141 | mpfi | 3.78 | 3.15 | 9.5 | 114 | 5400 | 19 | 25 | 22625 |

> [204 rows x 26 columns] Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full
> output data in a text editor

URLError:

```
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)ile /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:1282, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1281 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1282 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:1328, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1327     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1328 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:1277, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1276     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1277 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py:1037, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1036 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1037 self.send(msg)
   1039 if message_body is not None:
   1040 
...
-> 1351         raise URLError(err)
   1352     r = h.getresponse()
   1353 except:
```

Comment: can you include the code snippet that you're trying to run? and can you also provide (if you're able) the link to the csv. It's a lot more help than just an error output!

Comment: sure thing !! 
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data')

Comment: Someone edited the text, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do with this. The goal of the exercise was to create the data frame but I can't do it on python unless the error stops, because I can't bring the datas on my visual code !

Answer (score 0):

The SSL exception that is being thrown by pandas on this on this HTTPS URL is (most likely) due to the SSL certificate used by the server hosting the website ([www.archive.ics.uci.edu](http://www.archive.ics.uci.edu)) being invalid, expired, or not trusted by the client.
This leaves two solutions to this problem:

1. Use the **HTTP** url. This does not require an SSL certificate and therefore does not encounter this issue.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data', header=None)
print(df.head())
```

2. Create an unverified SSL context which will set the default SSL context to be unverified, allowing you to access the **HTTPS** URL without encountering SSL certificate validation issues

```py
import pandas as pd
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data', header=None)
print(df.head())
```

Let me know if either of these fixed your problem and happy coding!

Ps. Its worth noting that it is generally not recommended to use unverified SSL contexts in production environment - but for messing around in a notebook it is fine.

Comment: Hi ! I just tried your first verification and it totally worked !!! Thank you for your help, now I can get back on the coding track !!!

Comment: Great news! Could you please accept the answer by clicking the ✅ button so other people know that the solution works? Thanks!